# See Who Toggles S3 Inventory On/Off

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to see which user turned [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) On or Off? I've checked my CloudTrail's Event History but I don't see anything for this in the filters. Is it only possible if you have a trail on the specific bucket?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls Using AWS CloudTrail - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html), `PutBucketInventoryConfiguration` is not one of the events tracked by AWS CloudTrail.

If this is causing a concern, then you could restrict access to `PutBucketInventoryConfiguration` within IAM, to reduce the number of people permitted to make that call.